# Can "in order" ever mean "alright"?

Tags: meaning, expressions, idioms, synonyms

I have read in dictionaries (Longman and google, in particular) that "in order"
can sometimes be a synonym for saying "alright". An example would be:

> “I brought you the receipts,” says one.
>
> “In order,” answers the other. (with the meaning: *alright*)

My question to you is, is what Longman and google say about this correct? I’m asking
because I’ve never before heard someone using "in order" with the
meaning of "alright".
Here's the link: ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be-in-order The first line says: be in order = be correct, be right. That for me means "be alright, be okay".
Also on google: in order = appropriate in the circumstances. "a little bit of flattery was now in order".

Comment: Yes, the dictionary is correct, but that example is very stilted - is that really the sample from your source? 


I was tempted to down-vote this question, but didn't as it's from a relatively new user, but a better question might be about what kind of impression this usage gives to a reader/listener, whether it's widespread, or how you'd use it (compared to "all right" or "okay").

Finally, I'll just say that everything that I have ever learned was new to me when I first heard it - novelty is not a good enough reason to disbelieve something.

Comment: This 'all right' meaning doesn't fit at all for me. Can you give a link to your source? I don't see it. [Searching Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be-in-order) only gives 'to be in order', none of whose examples match yours.

Comment: "That appears to be in order" may be a response from some senior officer quickly  looking through the receipts they requested.

Comment: What is the publication age of your source? The information in it may be dated as this is not a current use of the phrase. Longman's online dictionary does not give that example for the phrase 'in order.'

Comment: I handed my documents to the border official: passport, letter of engagement, certification of professional status, certified translations and various other things that my lawyer thought would be useful. He leafed through them slowly, pausing once to consult a typed list kept under the glass countertop. His expression was impossible to read. “These appear to be **in order**”, he said at last. They were **alright** after all, I realized. I walked slowly to the exit, but inside my steps felt quick and light.

Comment: For Mitch:   Hi, here's the link: https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be-in-order                     The first line says:  be in order = be correct, be right.  That for me means <be alright, be okay>.

Comment: For KrisW:   The example is a made-up one, I came up with it, as that's how I would say it if I necessarily wanted to use <in order> instead of <alright>.

Comment: For Fisher:  I came up with the example as I was curios whether the german line <In Ordnung.> meaning <Alright.> finds a correspondent in English using literal translation of <in = in> and <Ordnung = order>. Prior to that I obviously looked it up and I found it in Longman and on google. The link for Longman is     https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be-in-order
           And this is what google says:   in order =  appropriate in the circumstances.
"a little bit of flattery was now in order"

Answer (score 1):

I think what you may be looking for here is what the OED lists as sense d, of the phrase ***in order*** - which is indicated as *Orig. US*.

> **d. Originally U.S. Appropriate to or befitting the occasion; suitable;
>   called for; correct**.
>
> 1850   in Rep. Deb. & Proc. Conv. Revision Constit. Ohio (1851) 52/1
>   I have prepared a resolution..and whenever it may be in order I shall
>   offer it.
>
> a1861   T. Winthrop John Brent (1862) viii. 85   If the gent has made
>   a remark what teches you, apologies is in order.
>
> 1878   J. H. Beadle Western Wilds xxv. 399   One week sufficed to
>   conclude my business in Oregon, but before leaving a few general notes
>   are in order.
>
> 1903   N.Y. Times 4 Sept. 2/3   Good byes were in order on the Erin
>   last night.
>
> 1962   G. Kubler Art & Archit. Anc. Amer. ix. 205   A few ‘glazed
>   sherds’ found during excavation: if these were plumbate, a Toltec Maya
>   date would be in order.
>
> 1977   N. Marsh Last Ditch vi. 151   Is it in order for us to ring up
>   your father and ask him to dine?
>
> 1992   Guns Illustr. (ed. 24) 8/1   Because I didn't order iron sights
>   on this 40XR, a scope was in order.

**I have never heard nor seen it used in answer to a question - as is suggested in the OP's example, however**.

Answer (score 0):

When you ask a question, refer the website that you sought the definition from. I'm unable to find the phrase in Longman, or any other dictionary.

Notice that *in order* is highly **contingent** on the preceding sentence, and dependent on the question.

Can you answer *in order* to someone who asks you an arbitrary question? Like, if someone asks you if you've watched the latest horror movie, would replying *in order* make sense? Or if someone asked if you've started a diet?

The phrase *in order* suits perfectly for the question stated in your question.

Comment: 'suits perfectly'? I wouldn't know what to make of it. Is it British English maybe?

Comment: No - not British English, @Mitch

Comment: @OldBrixtonian It ain't American English either (as far as I know). Anyone else want to claim it?

Comment: @Noaman Ali I thought your answer was useful until the last sentence. Was it a typo?

Comment: @Mitch No-one wants it! What I meant was, the specific usage in the original question was wrong. I'll do an answer.

Comment: @Mitch The longer phrase “Everything’s in order” might be more familiar.

Comment: @Mitch I think he's using *suits perfectly* where you or I might be more likely to say *fits perfectly* or perhaps *is perfectly well suited*.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian One of the verb definitions, at https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suit, defines suit as an intransitive verb, and means 'to be appropriate or satisfactory'. Unsure as to where the doubt is.

Comment: @tchrist Yes, that's the way I see it.

Comment: @Noaman Ali  I'm not discussing your use of the word "suit." I agreed with most of your answer but was surprised at the final paragraph.

Comment: @Lawrence Yes, that makes sense "Everything is in order.". And that does give the same impression as "Everything is all right." But 1) "In order" sounds really off as a response to (most) anything. and 2) just because two things in some context are similar, doesn't mean that they mean the same thing. 'fat' and 'obese' are very similar in one context, but that doesn't mean that "This steak is obese and juicy".

Answer (score 0):

"In order" is indeed a common, or slightly dated, expression in BrE. However, your example --

> “In order,” answers the other. (with the meaning: alright)

-- is faulty.

As [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-order) says,

> If you put or keep something in order, you make sure that it is tidy
>   or properly organized.

Some examples:

```
Your travel documents appear to be in order.
It was her job to keep the room in order.  
Someone comes in every day to check all is in order.
```

Comment: That's not what "your documents are in order" means: it means the documents are all valid, proper, or correct for the situation, not that they're alphabetically sorted or neatly placed in a folder. See order (noun) 9.b: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20order

Comment: @ Stuart F  I don't think I said it meant they were alphabetically sorted.